# ObjectInputStream constructor gives StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF

Tags: java, serialization, java-io, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am trying to use an ObjectOutputStream and an ObjectInputStream to store multiple BookLibrary objects in an ArrayList, but whenever I attempt to read in the data from the text file ("data.txt") that is supposed to contain the ArrayList information after stopping the program and running it again it gives me the above error on line 20 of the program. Here is the code at present:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Driver {
    public static ArrayList<BookLibrary> libraries;
    public static ObjectOutputStream output;
    public static ObjectInputStream input;
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        File file = new File("data.txt");
        
        libraries = new ArrayList<BookLibrary>();
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        else {
            try {
                input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                System.out.println("before reading from file");
                Driver.libraries = (ArrayList<BookLibrary>)input.readObject();
                System.out.println("after reading from file");
            } catch (EOFException e) {
                System.out.println("end of file reached");
            } finally {
                if (input != null) {
                    input.close();
                }
            }
        }
        if (output == null) {
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        }
        Driver.update();
        Frame frame = new Frame(Driver.libraries);
    }
    public static void update() {
        try {
            output.writeObject(libraries);
            output.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have made sure that all of the classes are Serializable and even have the same serialVersionUID, and have deleted the data file several times to try to clear out any corrupted data. The only thing that I can think of at this point is that the ObjectOutputStream is causing problems whenever it is initialized. I am a complete beginner when it comes to file handling so I have no idea what could be causing this issue, and I couldn't find any information on how to fix this problem. Any help would be appreciated at this point. Thanks!

Comment: The file was not created by an `ObjectOutputStream`. Otherwise it would start with hex AC. NB Serialized data is not text, and non-text data should not be saved in a file named `.txt`. NB (2) The `file.createNewFile()` line here is a complete waste of time and space.

Comment: @user207421 I have removed the unnecessary code and changed the file type to `.ser`. It still gives me the wrong header whenever I initialize the `ObjectOutputStream`. How can I be sure that the `ObjectOutputStream` is creating the file correctly?

Comment: Somebody else writing to the file? File already existed before you ran this code?

Comment: The file already existed before running the program. It reads in just fine if the output and input streams are used during the same life cycle but doesn’t work when the input stream tries to read in a file from a previous life cycle

Comment: Sounds very like someone else is writing to it.

Comment: Does this question [invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF when converting object from byte string](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjKj93poLaDAxULSWwGHSZoDHQQFnoECAoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F46818958%2Finvalid-stream-header-efbfbdef-when-converting-object-from-byte-string&usg=AOvVaw3oGkbmJ4X7TJKBt5vt751-&opi=89978449) ring any bells? Are you doing anything like that?